# Compiler warning: lambda return type cannot be deduced

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, compiler-warnings

Consider this example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "abcde4fghijk4l5mnopqrs6t8uvwxyz";
    std::string str2;

    std::remove_copy_if(str.begin(), str.end(),
        std::back_inserter(str2),
        [](char& c) {
            if (std::isdigit(c))
                return true;      // <----- warning here
            else
                return false;
        }
    );

    std::cout << str2 << '\n';
}
```

With GCC 4.6.1, this compiles fine and prints expected output (the alphabet) but I get a warning saying *"lambda return type can only be deduced when the return statement is the only statement in the function body"*.

Now, I know how to get rid of the warning (using trailing return type or simply saying `return isdigit(c);`), but I'm curious, since compiler doesn't warn for nothing (or so it should be): what could possibly go wrong in code like this? Does standard say anything about it?

Comment: The standard says it's ill-formed, so the compiler is obligated to show a warning at the least, and is free to refuse to compile it at all (as other compilers are likely to do).

Comment: @ildjarn Can you quote the standard on why is it ill formed?

Comment: @VJovic : No time right now, hence the comment instead of an answer. :-]

Comment: @Jrok oops sorry, bad reading

Comment: I do have to ask why you didn't just write `return std::isdigit(c);` though, which is both simpler AND solves the problem at hand.

Comment: @MarkB This is just an example, the real lambda isn't this trivial and I forgot to add trailing return type when writing it. From there on, it's just curiosity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @ildjarn says in his comment, your code is simply ill-formed according to the standard.

`§5.1.2 [expr.prim.lambda] p4`

> [...] If a *lambda-expression* does not include a *trailing-return-type*, it is as if the *trailing-return-type* denotes the following type:
>
> - if the *compound-statement* is of the form
>     `{` *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>* `return` *expression* ; `}`
>     the type of the returned expression after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1), array-to-pointer conversion
>     (4.2), and function-to-pointer conversion (4.3);
> - otherwise, `void`.
>
> [...]

That's it, basically if the code inside the curly brackets (called *compund-statement* in the standard) is anything but `return some_expr;`, the standard says the return type is undeducible and you get a `void` return type.

Comment: ...that will result in a compiler error in the OP example, when it encounters a `return` statement with a value.

Comment: @rodrigo: Correct, atleast it *should*. GCC is a bit more lenient with the return type deduction it seems.

Comment: @rodrigo : No, it's simply ill-formed. A compiler is free to accept ill-formed code as an extension, but is obligated to at least show a warning (§1.4/8), which GCC does in this case.

Comment: @ildjarn: Really? I thought ill-formed code is simply not valid.

Comment: @Xeo : "*A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional library functions), provided they do not alter the behavior of any well-formed program. Implementations are required to diagnose programs that use such extensions that are ill-formed according to this International Standard. Having done so, however, they can compile and execute such programs.*" 'Diagnose' in this context can mean 'warn'.

Comment: @ildjarn: Didn't you just say in a comment to the OP that you have no time for standard quotes right now? :P

Comment: @Xeo : The lambda quote takes a lot of time to format properly; this one didn't. :-P

Comment: And since a compiler may diagnose any additional issue they see fit, and the standard doesn't require any specific message, a compiler that says "there may be errors" will be always correct!

Comment: According to this standard quote, the return type of the lambda in the example should be `void` and in that case the code shouldn't compile, no matter compiler extensions, no?

Comment: @jrok : If compiler extensions that allowed otherwise invalid code to compile weren't allowed, then compiler extensions would be pretty useless. ;-] (C.f. GCC's support of VLAs.)

Comment: @Barry: Like the OP said, and the quote says, yes, adding a trailing-return-type will make it work.

Answer (score 3):

It is worth noting that this issue has been rectified in C++14. The language now correctly deduces the return type as the OP expected. From the draft standard [7.1.6.4.11]:

> If the type of an entity with an undeduced placeholder type is needed
>   to determine the type of an expression, the program is ill-formed.
>   Once a return statement has been seen in a function, however, the
>   return type deduced from that statement can be used in the rest of the
>   function, including in other return statements. [ Example:
>
> ```
> auto n = n; // error, n’s type is unknown
> auto f();
> void g() { &f; } // error, f’s return type is unknown
> auto sum(int i) {
> if (i == 1)
>     return i; // sum’s return type is int
> else
>     return sum(i-1)+i; // OK, sum’s return type has been deduced
> }
> ```
>
> —end example ]