# reversing the letters of the words in a string

Tags: c++, arrays, pass-by-reference

I want to reverse the letters of the words in a string and have to store it in the same array.example: i/p: hi how are you o/p: ih woh era uoy. i wrote this programs but it just prints the same string without reversing and the program is not terminating it continues to print something. i cant findout the mistake. please help me and tell me the correct code.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void stre(char (&a1)[20], int j1, int i1)
{
    char b[20];
    for(int k=i1-j1;k<i1;k++)
        b[k]=a1[i1-k-1];
    for(k=i1-j1;k<i1;k++);
        a1[k]=b[k];
}


void main()
{
    clrscr();
    int j;
    char a[20];
    gets(a);
    for(int i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        j++;
        if(a[i]==' ')
        { 
            stre(a,j,i);
            j=0;
        }
    }
    stre(a,j,i);
    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
    cout<<a[j];
    getch();
}
```

friends after your answers i removed the semicolon in the for loop and also initialized j=0 but still i am not able to get the required output now for the i/p:hi how are you o/p:ihh hi hhi hhi. still need your help.

Comment: You are producing a terrible mix of C and C++... Try to stick with C++ streams and formatted Input in your case.

Comment: not sure if duplicate, but a similar question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879348/reverse-every-word-in-a-stringshould-handle-space

Comment: A `gets` on an array of 20 `char`?  Any use of `gets` is an error, but with only 20 `char`, it's an error almost certain to manifest itself rather quickly.

Comment: And for what it's worth: a much simpler (and better) solution would be to break the string up into words, and call `std::reverse` on each word.

Comment: Not to mention that there's no such header as `<conio.h>` on must systems, and it's deprecated where it exists, that `j` is never initialized, and that `main` isn't allowed to return a `void`.

Comment: i need to get the string with spaces. so i used gets(). is there a method to get a string with spaces without using any functions(just by using cin)

Comment: @user2483349 ,  can you updat =e your latest code in some online source? like (this)[http://ideone.com/]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
  #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;


       int main() {

int j =0;
char a[20] = "hi how are you";
char b[20] = "";
    int l=0;
    for(int i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++){

        if(a[i]==' ' ||a[i+1]=='\0'){
          cout<<j<<' '<<i;
           if(a[i+1]=='\0'){
               b[l++] = ' ';


           }


          for(int k=i;k>=j;k--){
              b[l]=a[k];
              l++;
          }
          for(int k=j;k<=i;k++){
            cout<<b[k];
            a[k] = b[k];
          }  


        cout<<endl;
        j = i+1;

        }
    }
   cout << a;
    return 0;

  }
```

Comment: i guess the OP is first making a temporary copy in the array b and then copying character by character to the original array. So, running the loop completely (And not until half of the length) is correct.

Answer (score 5):

```
for(k=i1-j1;k<i1;k++);
  a1[k]=b[k];
```

The semilcolon after the for loop prevents the last action from occuring multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

This for loop is terminated by the semi-colon:

```
for(k=i1-j1;k<i1;k++);
                    ^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that is not perfect by any means, but at least, it tries to be more like C++ than C:

http://ideone.com/f5vciW

first: tokenize into words and space sequences

```
//the spaces should be preserved
std::string test("hi   how are you"),reference("ih   woh era uoy");
 std::vector<std::string> tokens;
tokenize(test,tokens);
```

then reverse the tokens

```
for (auto& token : tokens)
    std::reverse(token.begin(),token.end());
```

assemble tokens into a string buffer

```
std::stringstream buf;
for (auto token : tokens)
    buf<<token;
```

check the result

```
std::string res=buf.str();
assert(res==reference);
```

where the tokenizer looks like that:

```
template <typename TContainer,typename TString>
void tokenize(TString input,TContainer& res)
{

    if (input.length()<2) {
        res.push_back(input);
        return;
    }

    typename TString::const_iterator pos=input.begin();
    bool space_state=std::isspace(input[0],std::locale());
    for (typename TString::const_iterator it=input.begin(); it!=input.end();
            ++it) {
        bool is_space=std::isspace(*it,std::locale());
        if (is_space!=space_state) {
            res.push_back(TString(pos,it));
            pos=it;
            space_state=is_space;
        }
    }

    //the rest
    if (pos!=input.end()) {
        res.push_back(
         TString(
          pos,
          static_cast<typename TString::const_iterator>(input.end())
         ));
    }

}
```

Comment: Surely that's going to reverse the order of the words. The OP wants to keep the words in the same order, but reverse the letters in each word. See his example above the code.

Comment: here's an updated answer. The tokenizer can be definitely further refactored, as well as the rest of the code ... It works for your example at least

Comment: check out the even shorter, and more efficient answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17147560/847349

Answer (score 0):

you passed  `j` without assigning the value. so it will be garbage.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two things in your code that may not result in the expected output:

1)

```
int j;
```

should be replaced with

```
int j=0;
```

And

```
for(k=i1-j1;k<i1;k++);
    a1[k]=b[k];
```

the semicolon after the for loop needs to be removed.

FYI, this mixing of C and C++ code is not recommended (it's compromising readability). please stick to either one of them.

Answer (score 0):

A similar example is shown on [this site.](http://code.cheraus.com/codes/cplus/reverse_word_string.php) They've also used almost the same approach that you'v e chosen(reversing each word by counting number of spaces)  by with the help of stack data structure.
**Make sure you have the STL library installed in your environment to run this code.**
 Better run this code on linux platform.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another, shorter version, doing the inversion in-line without using an extra buffer:

http://ideone.com/hs9NZ7

the criterion for the tokenizer is the change in the `isspace` condition:

```
auto next_token=
 [&](char c) {
       return std::isspace(c,loc)!=std::isspace(*pos,loc);
 };
```

using that we can go through the input string and visit the tokens:

```
for (auto it=std::find_if(pos,test.end(),next_token);
          it!=test.end();
          it=std::find_if(pos,test.end(),next_token))
```

reversing them and updating the current position

```
std::reverse(pos,it);
pos=it;
```

and not forgetting the leftover token.