# Reverse string code ignoring spaces

Tags: c, string

I've written some code which is supposed to reverse an inputted string. Though, on print I only get the string up until the first space. I'm assuming its related to the function which reads input, scanf.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char *array){
int i;
int j = (strlen(array) - 1);
int p = (strlen(array));
char newArray[strlen(array)];

printf("%i", j);


for(i = 0; i < strlen(array); i++){
    newArray[i] = array[j];
    j--;
}

printf("%s", newArray);

//printf("%i", strlen(newArray));
/*  int a;
for(a = 0; a < p; a++){
    printf("%c", newArray[a]);*/
}
}



int main(){

char string[50];
scanf("[^\n]", &string);
reverse(string);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [reverse every word in a string(should handle space)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879348/reverse-every-word-in-a-stringshould-handle-space)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
scanf("[^\n]", &string);
```

to

```
scanf("%[^\n]", string);
```

and

```
newArray[i]='\0';
```

add to after `for`

```
for(i = 0; i < strlen(array); i++){
    newArray[i] = array[j];
    j--;
}
newArray[i]='\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `scanf("[^\n]", &string);` to

`scanf("%[^\n]s", string);`