# How do I reverse each word in a sentence string like "I love computer science" using c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to reverse each word in the sentence that I input.

For example:
Input= I love computer Science

Output = I evol retupmoc ecneicS

But this is what actually outputs with the input from above:

Output = ecneicS retupmoc evol I

I  don't know how to fix it please help. Thank you vert much.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Prototype
void swap (char&, char&);
int main()
{

// Vars
string sentence;

// Input
cout << "Welcome to Reverse-the-words" << endl;
cout << "Enter your sentence, word, or phrase" << endl;
getline(cin,sentence);


     for (int i=0; i < sentence.length()/2; i++)
     {
        swap (sentence [i], sentence [sentence.length()-i-1]);
     }

// Output
cout << "Your phrase with all of the words reversed is " << endl;
cout << sentence << endl ;

return 0;
}

void swap(char &v1, char &v2)
{
    char temp;
    temp = v1;
    v1= v2;
    v2=temp
}
```

Comment: You have made no attempt at all to "detect" words in the input...

Comment: You could use `std::swap`

Comment: I already used a swap for the sentence so would I just do another swap statement inside the same for loop replacing sentence.length with word.length?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse every word in a string (should handle space)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879348/reverse-every-word-in-a-string-should-handle-space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update of your code to reverse every word in a sentence:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Prototype
void swap (char&, char&);
int main()
{

// Vars
string sentence;

// Input
cout << "Welcome to Reverse-the-words" << endl;
cout << "Enter your sentence, word, or phrase" << endl;
getline(cin,sentence);

     int word_begin = 0;
     for (int i=0; i <=sentence.length(); i++)
     {  

         if (!isalpha(sentence[i]))
         {   

             for (int j = word_begin; j < (i - (i - word_begin)/2); j++)
             {
                 swap(sentence[j], sentence[i - j + word_begin - 1]);
             }

             word_begin = i + 1;
         }
     }

// Output
cout << "Your phrase with all of the words reversed is " << endl;
cout << sentence << endl ;

return 0;
}

void swap(char &v1, char &v2)
{
    char temp;
    temp = v1;
    v1= v2;
    v2 = temp;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but when I g++ the code, it tells me there is an operator error with word_begin and that word_begin is a conflicting declaration

Comment: Okay I fixed my error I was declaring word_begin twice thank you so much! I understand it and it works, you explained it very simply much appreciated!

Comment: If I enter something like : My number is 123-456-7890, the number does not get flipped so what can I do to make the number work? and the same with apostrophes, if I enter " I'm "  it just gives me " I'm " instead of " m'I "

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use std::reverse

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Vars
    string sentence;

    // Input
    cout << "Welcome to Reverse-the-words" << endl;
    cout << "Enter your sentence, word, or phrase" << endl;
    getline(cin, sentence);

    istringstream iss(sentence);
    string word;
    cout << "Your phrase with all of the words reversed is " << endl;
    while (iss >> word) {
        std::reverse(word.begin(), word.end());
        cout<<word.c_str()<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output

```
Welcome to Reverse-the-words
Enter your sentence, word, or phrase
I love science
Your phrase with all of the words reversed is
I evol ecneics
```

Comment: This won't work if the string contains successive whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

After getting the sentence, get each word from the sentence into a new variable, then reverse and print it.

Tip: you need a for loop inside a for loop.

```
for word in sentence:
    for character in word:
        /* your code to reverse the word */
    /* print the word */
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always good practice to use the standard library. Here's what I could come up with to reverse words inplace while maintaining successive whitespace:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

std::string& reverse_words(std::string& sentence) {
  auto first = sentence.find_first_not_of(' ');
  auto last  = sentence.find_first_of(' ', first);
  while (last < std::string::npos) {
    std::reverse(&sentence[first], &sentence[last]);
    first = sentence.find_first_not_of(' ', last);
    last  = sentence.find_first_of(' ', first);
  }
  std::reverse(&sentence[first], &sentence[sentence.size()]);
  return sentence;
}
```

There is maybe a way to write this more elegantly but I think you will get the idea.