# How can I get which part of an if expression is true?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, if-statement

Assume I have code like:

```
if(condition1 || condition2 || condition 3 || condition4)
{
// this inner part will be executed if one of the conditions is true.
// Now I want to know by which condition this part is executed.
}
```

Comment: Aside from printing `cout << "condition1=" << coundition1 << " condition2=" << condition2  ... `?

Comment: @captain: fancy explaining a bit more?

Comment: @captain What makes you think that his `if` can be rewritten as a `switch`.  If his `condition1` etc. are actually variables, it certainly can't, and if they are arbitrary expressions, it can't be either.

Comment: While executing inner part.The compiler knows which condition is true. And I want to know which condition was true to execute inner part.

Comment: @mahesh elaborate your question, maybe you need to redesign your if statement

Comment: you can put all your conditions inside seperate functions and call these functions inside if condition. use print statements inside functions. if(function1 == 1 | function2 ==1 | function3==1), in short you can call functions inside if.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sure there are better ways to do this, here's one:

```
int i = 0;
auto check = [&i](bool b)->bool
{
    if (!b) ++i;
    return b;
};

if (check(false) || // 0
    check(false) || // 1
    check(true)  || // 2
    check(false))   // 3
{
    std::cout << i; // prints 2
}
```

Comment: The trailing return type isn't necessary btw

Comment: @user1233963 It won't be in C++14, in C++11 it is.

Comment: @user1233963 Try compiling with `-pedantic`. I once [thought the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582610/compiler-warning-lambda-return-type-cannot-be-deduced) as you :)

Comment: That warning is only when you return in conditionals. A single return (like in this case) works fine

Comment: I never said it didn't work, it's just ill-formed as per C++11 spec.

Comment: No, it's not, not in this case

Comment: @user1233963 I rest my case, the authoritative text is in 
ISO/IEC 14882:2011, paragraph 5.1.2/4. I hope we agree that having `->bool` there at least does no harm :)

Answer (score 2):

|| is short circuit evaluation, so you can have code like this :

```
if(condition1 || condition2 || condition 3 || condition4)
{
    if (condition1 ) 
    {
            //it must be condition1 which make the overall result true
    }
    else if (condition2)
    {
            //it must be condition2 which make the overall result true
    }
    else if (condition3)
    {
            //it must be condition3 which make the overall result true
    }
    else
    {
            //it must be condition4 which make the overall result true
    }

    // this inner part will executed if one of the condition true. Now I want to know by which condition this part is executed.
}
else
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the conditions are independent of each other, you need to check them separately, or, if they belong to one variable, you can use a switch statement

```
bool c1;
bool c2
if ( c1 || c2 )
{
    // these need to be checked separately
}


int i; // i should be checked for multiple conditions. Here switch is most appropriate
switch (i)
{
    case 0: // stuff
            break;
    case 1: // other stuff
            break;
    default: // default stuff if none of the conditions above is true
}
```

Comment: some if statement can't switch to switch, for example, `if (str=="something")`

Answer (score 0):

Without a `switch` you can use only `or` and `if` statements:

```
if(condition1 || condition2 || condition 3 || condition4) {
  // this inner part will executed if one of the condition true. 
  //Now I want to know by which condition this part is executed.
  if ( condition1 || condition2 ) { 
    if ( condition1 ) 
       printf("Loop caused by 1");
    else 
       printf("Loop caused by 2");
  else 
    if ( condition3) 
       printf("Loop caused by 3");
    else
       printf("Loop caused by 4");
}
```

I'm not sure that this is the most efficient thing you've ever seen, but it will identify which of the four conditions caused entry into the `if ...` block.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know for programmatic reasons, i.e. run different code depending on which condition is true, you could do something like this

```
if (condition1)
{
    ...
}
else if (condition2)
{
    ...
}
else if (condition3)
{
    ...
}
else if (condition4)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

If you only want to know for debugging reasons, just do a printout.

Answer (score 0):

What about the comma operator? 
By using that logical operators follow the short circuit evaluation method, the following works fine:

```
 int w = 0; /* w <= 0 will mean "no one is true" */
 if ( (w++, cond1) || (w++, cond2) || ... || (w++, condN) )
   printf("The first condition that was true has number: %d.\n", w);
```