# C++11 restrictions on lambda return type

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, return, language-lawyer

I'm reading here on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) about how a return type of a C++11 lambda is deduced:

> if the body consists of the single `return` statement, the return type is the type of the returned expression (after rvalue-to-lvalue, array-to-pointer, or function-to-pointer implicit conversion)

So I think that means that a lambda can only have one return statement. But why does it work with multiple return statements still?

This [compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8276a87f293b96da) on both compilers:

```
auto f = [] (bool c1, bool c2) {
    if (c1) return 1;
    if (c2) return 2;
    else    return 3;
};
```

Comment: The page you link to also shows that the rules changed in C++14. My first guess is that the compilers are implementing the C++14 rules even in C++11 mode.

Comment: @hvd Yup, that's what I suspected but I was still skeptical.

Comment: FWIW, I checked what C++11 says, and it matches what you already found online, so yes, it should generate a compile-time diagnostic. That said, implementing the C++14 rule cannot cause valid C++11 code to be rejected, so it may only be a minor problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is slightly imprecise. [expr.prim.lambda]/4:

> If a *lambda-expression* does not include a *lambda-declarator*, it is
>   as if the *lambda-declarator* were `()`. If a *lambda-expression* does
>   not include a *trailing-return-type*, it is as if the
>   trailing-return-type denotes the following type:
>
> - if the compound-statement is of the form
>
>   `{` *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>*opt*</sub>`return` *expression* `; }`
>
>   the type of the returned expression after lvalue-to-rvalue
>     conversion (4.1), array-to-pointer conversion (4.2), and
>     function-to-pointer conversion (4.3);
> - otherwise, `void`.

So the return type is only deduced if the whole body of the lambda expression only consists of one sole `return` statement.
 Both GCC and Clang are not standard conforming in this case as they issue an error message if and only if two `return` statements lead to inconsistent deductions. This is because they already implemented the C++14 standard which deducts the return type even with multiple `return` statements and/or multiple other statements present. [expr.prim.lambda]/4 specifies that

> The lambda return type is `auto`, which is replaced by the
>   *trailing-return-type* if provided **and/or deduced from `return` statements as described in 7.1.6.4**.

§7.1.6.4/9

> If a function with a declared return type that contains a placeholder
>   type has multiple `return` statements, the return type is deduced for
>   each `return` statement. If the type deduced is not the same in each
>   deduction, the program is ill-formed.

Comment: FWIW, [I asked about this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582610/compiler-warning-lambda-return-type-cannot-be-deduced) years ago :)

Answer (score 3):

It works with your example because all the `return` statements return values of the same type. But try changing the second `return` to a different type, for example:

```
auto f = [] (bool c1, bool c2) {
    if (c1) return 1;
    if (c2) return "";
    else    return 3;
};
```

Compiling this with clang++ yields the following error:

```
main.cpp:3:13: error: return type 'const char *' must match previous return type 'int' when lambda expression has unspecified explicit
      return type
    if (c2) return "";
        ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: He's asking why multiple return statements are allowed despite what the quote says (that there may be only one). This has nothing to do with the type of the return expression.

Comment: @0x499602D2 The (incomplete) quote doesn’t say that multiple return statements aren’t allowed, though. The complete quote does seem to imply that, but it’s simply imprecise.

Comment: @KonradRudolph That's what the OP thinks.